# ESAPI SecurityWrapper and REST Interfaces

Tags: java, rest, esapi

I have a Spring Boot application that exposes a number of REST interfaces. Company web development security standards mandate the use of the ESAPI SecurityWrapper filter in my application.

ESAPI SecurityWrapper forcibly overwrites Http Status codes to 200 in order to  `confound attackers using automated scanners.` This has obvious implications on my REST interface.

Is there an acknowledged work around for the SecurityWrapper in order to allow the Http Status codes to be left unaffected. All my attempts have so far been extremely hacky and are unlikely to be approved by the security guys here.

Comment: Mandating SecurityWrapperFilter is actually a horrible policy, for exactly this reason:  The security implementation gets in the way of expected normal use.

Comment: So, when searching the ESAPI source code, I don't see where `SecurityWrapperResponse.sendError(int)` is getting called.  Are you sure it's overwriting your responses?

Comment: @avgvstvs : I've run it thru the debugger and it definitely gets called. The filter replaces the request and response objects with the Wrapped equivalents so any call to the request and response objects that your code makes actually calls the implementation in the wrapping object - so my code sets the response code to 500 if there's a fatal error, but the method that it calls actually ignores the value I have passed in and replaces it with HttpStatus.OK

Comment: Well, it won't help you immediately, but I opened a ticket:  https://github.com/ESAPI/esapi-java-legacy/issues/383

Answer (score 0):

It should be easy to extend SecurityWrapperFilter if you want a custom behavior. Confounding attackers is a good thing.

Comment: Actually, this confounded a developer pretty effectively as it took a while for me to identify what was screwing with my http return codes .... And subclassing wasn't as easy as you first think. The behavour comes from an object thst is `new`ed from within the filter.